# wxPython migration from 4.0.7 to 4.1.0: ListCtrl error while event handling

Tags: c++, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm currently migrating from wxPython 4.0.7 to wxPython 4.1.0. This changes the wx version from 3.0.x to 3.1.x.

Tl;dr:
Using a `wx.ListCtrl` I sometimes get an error when I call `event.Skip()` inside a `wxEVT_SIZE` event handler. To `Skip()` or not to `Skip()`? (i.e. whats the default event handling for a `wxEVT_SIZE` and do I need it?)

---

Long Version:

Using `wx.ListCtrl` with `event.Skip` inside the `wxEVT_SIZE` handler produces an error in **some** of my forms (so I think there must be more to it). Now, I couldn't strip any of the occurrences down to have a minimal example, since the error kinda disappears randomly when I remove (seemingly) unrelated parts of the code. The error even disappears (sometimes) when I replace a long label with a shorter label. However, changing the Frame or Panel size doesn't change anything.

Here is, what I found out:

- The error is definitely linked to the usage of the `wx.ListCtrl` class
- The error only occurs, when a function is bound to the `wxEVT_COMMAND_LIST_ITEM_ACTIVATED` event, though an empty handler (with or without `Skip()`) is enough to provoke the error.
- The error only occurs when a function is bound to the `wxEVT_SIZE` event
- The error only occurs when I call `event.Skip()` in the `wxEVT_SIZE` handler

It seems like I can simply remove the `event.Skip()` call inside the `wxEVT_SIZE` handler and be done, but the relevant C++ Code seems like there is more going on.

Here is the error (note: the error does not crash the wxApp):

```
wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "nNew != dynamicEvents.size()" failed at ..\..\src\common\event.cpp(1926) in wxEvtHandler::SearchDynamicEventTable():

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError: <class 'wx._core.SizeEvent'> returned a result with an error set
```

The relevant C++ Code in the github repository can be found here: https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/e803408058186a7a9a61c456246f145abcaccd13/src/common/event.cpp#L1926

(Hint: This is the pinned wxWidget-version used in the wxPython 4.1.0 Release)

Any wx & C++ experts here, that may know what's going on?

Comment: why do you need to handle EVT_SIZE in the first place? Can you create MCE to show the error?

Comment: When using EVT_SIZE, you absolutely have to call event.Skip(). Unless you know what you are doing. But when you use EVT_COMMAND_LIST_ITEM_ACTIVATED you don't need to call that function. In fact there it will give more harm. Also - do you use sizers in you code?

Comment: Yes, we use mostly PySizer and BoxSizer together. We have a custom function to adjust the column width on resize (we need some columns with a fixed width, the rest of the available size should be evenly distributed among the remaining columns). I'm still trying to create a minimal example, but as I wrote, the error disappears even on some small (seemingly unrelated) changes to our code base

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this assert can only be triggered if a handler calls `Bind()` from its event handler, but skips the event, i.e. pretends that the event wasn't handled at all. In an ideal world, this should be possible and I think the assert is actually over-eager and needs to be relaxed, but for now, if you really need to do it like this, you must either:

1. Postpone calling `Bind()` by using `CallAfter()`.
2. Or avoid calling `event.Skip()`.

(note that the assert won't be always triggered in this case, you also need to delete a handler that was previously connected to the same object shortly before).

But generally speaking you should call `Skip()` unless you have fully processed the event and don't want any other handlers, either those in the base class or the built-in ones, to run after yours. For `wxEVT_SIZE` it means that you've performed the re-layout of the window yourself and don't want the base class to do anything. So the solution (1) is better because it can be used even if you do want the base class handler to run.

Comment: Perfect. CallAfter solved the problem for me, thank you.